# Odd behaviour with Map in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I was writing code and I noticed some odd behavior in Groovy when I am dealing with XML and Maps. I thought about it and can't figure out why is it happening and should it that way.

I wrote sample code with 3 examples. Crucial difference between map1 & map3 is only on the following part:

Map1:

```
map1 << ["${it.name()}":it.value()]
```

Map3:

```
map3["${it.name()}"]=it.value()
```

Here is full code, you can copy-paste it into Groovy console:

```
def xml = '<xml><head>headHere</head><body>bodyHere</body></xml>'


Map map1 = [:]

def node = new XmlParser().parseText(xml) 

node.each {
      map1 << ["${it.name()}": it.value()]
} 

println map1
println map1["head"]

println ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"



Map map2 = [:]

map2 << ["head":"headHere"]
map2 << ["body":"bodyHere"]

println map2
println map2["head"]

println "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"



def xml2 = '<xml><head>headHere</head><body>bodyHere</body></xml>'    

Map map3 = [:]

def node2 = new XmlParser().parseText(xml2) 

node2.each {
      map3["${it.name()}"]=it.value()
} 

println map3
println map3["head"]
```

The result that I am getting is following:

```
[head:[headHere], body:[bodyHere]]
null

[head:headHere, body:bodyHere]
headHere

[head:[headHere], body:[bodyHere]]
[headHere]
```

Even thou map1 and map3 look the same, the result of map["head"] is totally different, first gives null and second gives the actual result. I don't understand why is it happening. I spent some time on it and still don't get it. I used `.getProperty()` to get info on a class, but it looks the same and feels the same on both maps and object inside. I tried couple more things and nothing gives me any idea on what is happening. I even tried different OS (Win XP, Mac OS) and still nothing.

I don't have any ideas anymore, please can one some explain odd behavior, why is it happening and what is the difference between `map << [key:object]` and `map[key] = object`?

Thank you.

Comment: There's a section on the [Strings and GStrings documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString) page for Groovy that warns about this.  (see: ___GStrings aren't Strings___ about 2/3 of the way down)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One thing that might help is, don't use GStrings for your keys.  Groovy supports using objects directly as keys by wrapping them in parentheses.

From [the manual](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections#Collections-Maps):

> Map keys are strings by default: [a:1] is equivalent to ["a":1]. But if you really want a variable to become the key, you have to wrap it between parentheses: [(a):1].

Fully working example:

```
def xml = '<xml><head>headHere</head><body>bodyHere</body></xml>'

Map map1 = [:]
def node = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
node.each {
    map1 << [ (it.name()): it.value() ]
}

println map1
println map1["head"]
println ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"

Map map2 = [:]

map2 << ["head":"headHere"]
map2 << ["body":"bodyHere"]

println map2
println map2["head"]

println "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"

def xml2 = '<xml><head>headHere</head><body>bodyHere</body></xml>'

Map map3 = [:]

def node2 = new XmlParser().parseText(xml2)

node2.each {
    map3[it.name()] = it.value()
}

println map3
println map3["head"]
```

The output is:

```
[head:[headHere], body:[bodyHere]]
[headHere]
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
[head:headHere, body:bodyHere]
headHere
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
[head:[headHere], body:[bodyHere]]
[headHere]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demonstration of this [quirk of double quoted strings in Groovy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_double_quoted_string):

> Double quoted strings are plain `java.lang.String` if there’s no
>   interpolated expression, but are `groovy.lang.GString` instances if
>   interpolation is present.

```
groovy:000> m = [:]
===> {}
groovy:000> tmp = "wat"
===> wat
groovy:000> key = "${tmp}"
===> wat
groovy:000> m << ["${key}": "hi"]
===> {wat=hi}
groovy:000> m["${key}"] = "hi"
===> hi
groovy:000> m
===> {wat=hi, wat=hi}
groovy:000> m["wat"] = "fuuuuuu!"
===> fuuuuuu!
groovy:000> m
===> {wat=hi, wat=fuuuuuu!}
groovy:000> m.keySet().each { println it.class }
class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
class java.lang.String
```

Enjoy ;)

Comment: Look at the classes of the keys.

Comment: I understand that I am looking at different objects and therefore the reason I get null in my code. But what I don't understand is why in one case it is GString and in another is String.

More over, if value for the key is GString or anything else - fine. But key seems to be a bit odd... I mean there is no limitation on what kind of class keys is, but if I expect to have all key as strings and I get GString - well that's gonna lead to some bug/issues.