# Node misbehaving with interpolated string

Tags: groovy

When I create a child node using an interpolated string I am unable to access that node again using dot notation.  When I try to access the node in question I just get `null`.  I can get the node if I loop through `children()` and hunt for it, but I shouldn't have to do that.  The following code duplicates the problem:

```
// All works as expected when an interpolated string isn't used to create the child node
def rootNode = new Node(null, "root")
def childNode = new Node(rootNode, "child", [attr: "test"])
def childNodeCopy = rootNode.child[0]
println childNode.toString() // child[attributes={attr=test}; value=[]]
println childNodeCopy.toString() // child[attributes={attr=test}; value=[]]
println childNode.toString() == childNodeCopy.toString() // true

// But when an interpolated string is used the child node cannot be accessed from the root
rootNode = new Node(null, "root")
def childName = "child"
childNode = new Node(rootNode, "$childName", [attr: "test"])
childNodeCopy = rootNode.child[0]
println childNode.toString() // child[attributes={attr=test}; value=[]]
println childNodeCopy.toString() // null
println childNode.toString() == childNodeCopy.toString() // false
```

Comment: What does Node.toString look like?

Comment: @tim_yates I added some comments to my code.  Is that what you were looking for?  BTW, the posted code will run if pasted in a `.groovy` file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhhh, it's because internally, <s>`Node` must be storing the node names as keys in a map</s> actually, it just iterates through the names of the nodes, but as it's in Java, it won't find the children as `string.equals( groovyString )` will never be true

And as Groovy Strings are not Strings, `rootNode.child` is returning `null`

As a workaround, you can do:

```
childNode = new Node(rootNode, "$childName".toString(), [attr: "test"]) 
childNodeCopy = rootNode.child[0]
```

Comment: I thought I had this same issue somewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7591157/438992

Comment: Using `toString()` or `as String` works, but it isn't very Groovy.  Why don't they make `Node.java` into `Node.groovy` and modify the `get()` method to include a call to `toString()` before `.equals()`?